# Using the URLconf defined in chatbottest.urls

Tags: django

I use Pycharm,django2.0.4
I started Django yesterday. 
I faced one error.

Using the URLconf defined in chatbottest.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 
1. admin/ 
2. globalHaksik/

The empty path didn't match any of these. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW3z2.jpg)

setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'globalHaksik',

]
```

chatbottest\urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('globalHaksik/', include('globalHaksik.urls')),
]
```

globalHaksik\urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('keyboard/', views.keyboard),
    ]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def keyboard(request):
    return JsonResponse({
        'type': 'buttons',
        'buttons': ['학식', '배달음식']
    })
```

I do not know the correct answer if I look for the same error on this site.
Please kindly answer me.

Comment: what is the exact url that you are trying to access?

Comment: If app user request keyboard url, I want to print view.py

Comment: ok, then accessing `/globalHaksik/keyboard/` should work

Comment: Could you explain why i need to add an empty pattern to access it?

Comment: If you just need to access `/globalHaksik/keyboard/` then you dont need to add the empty pattern. I have updated the answer now. Feel free to accept it if it helped you

Comment: I don't understand your update answer ㅠㅠ.
I'm sorry I did not understand.
Are you telling me to add  chatbottest \ urls.py path('globalHaksik/', include('globalHaksik.urls'))? it is already defined.

Comment: No I am not telling you to add it. I am just saying that if you want to access keyboard, the url would be `/globalHaksik/keyboard/` since that is how it is defined in urls.py right now

Comment: Thank you for your kindly help!!

Comment: If this answer helped you, please feel free to accept it

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Looks like you are just trying to access the URL leading to views.keyboard. So the url that you need to access is `/globalHaksik/keyboard/` (and not just `/keyboard`) since the path defined in chatbottest\urls.py has `globalHaksik/` in it:

```
path('globalHaksik/', include('globalHaksik.urls')),
```

---

If you are trying to access `/`, then you need to add the empty pattern as follows:

chatbottest\urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.your_view_name),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('globalHaksik/', include('globalHaksik.urls')),
    ]
```

If you are trying to access `/globalHaksik/`, then you you need to add the empty pattern to globalHaksik\urls.py:

globalHaksik\urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.your_view_name),
        path('keyboard/', views.keyboard),
        ]
```